# Ajax success function won't fire even when the call succeeds

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm using ajax to save data in a cakephp app. The ajax works to the extent that it saves the data -- when I click on the submit button, the comment saves to the database and even automagically appears in my list of comments. However, no matter what I try nothing happens in the 'success' function. I can't get an alert but nor can I get an error alert.

What's going on? Does this have something to do with how cake returns the data? In my controller's add function, the saving part works. The part that checks if the request is ajax doesn't seem to do anything. I've tried putting a redirect in there and the page doesn't redirect. To be clear: I don't want the page to be redirected; I want to stay on the page. However, since I can't do anything on success, I can't display a 'saved' message or clear the form fields or anything else. Ideas?

```
// my jquery script
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Turn submit button into an ajax call
  $('#save-comment input').click(function(){
    saveComment();
});

// This function is called when the "save" button is clicked
function saveComment() 
{  
  var formdata = $('#comment-form').serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/cakeblog/comments/add",
    data: formdata,
    success: function(result) {
      alert("success");
    },
    error:function (){
      alert('error');
    }
  });
 }
});

// my controller
class CommentsController extends AppController {
  public $name = 'Comments';

public function add() {
  if (!empty($this->data)) {
    if($this->Comment->save($this->data)){
  if($this->request->is('ajax')){
        // nothing I put here seems to do anything
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
  } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Message sent');
    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
  }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the error console?

Comment: What do the headers of your response look like? Check the network section of your console for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't returned Http Response in your controller. You need to return `Http Response` in `function add()` . For that you need to `echo` in your controller.

Seems like detecting ajax is wrong... use below to detect ajax.

```
$this->set('isAjax', $this->RequestHandler->isAjax());
```

And one more thing. you are redirecting in your controller .u can't redirect in that view. you have to do this in success call of your ajax.

Comment: Shouldn't matter. An empty body is a valid response.

Comment: Can you please show me what you mean? I'm not sure how I'd do that (I'm using cake 2.0)

Answer (score 0):

The code looks correct. Some pointers:

1. Check the JavaScript console for errors?
2. Check the network view of your browser: What does the server send as reply for this AJAX call? Does it respond at all?

Comment: I had an error in my error function so it wasn't giving me the error alert. I'm now getting that alert, so clearly I'm not having success as defined by ajax (even though the data is saving). I tried capturing some error information by putting arguments in the error function like so: error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ alert("errors: " + xhr + " ajaxOptions " + ajaxOptions + " thrown " + thrownError);. The alert gives me this: error: [object Object] options error thrownError:   (no data for thrownError). WHy the error?